# how to insert picture into word doc from access database using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm trying to read picture from access attachment field and then insert it into word document. As the below code show, I could read an attachment into a file and then insert it to word doc but it's inefficient and I want a way to directly do this. any idea?

```
Option Compare Database

Sub picloader()

    Dim appword As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear

    Set appword = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set appword = New Word.Application

    End If

    appword.Visible = True
    appword.Activate

    'word doc to save picture
    Set doc1 = appword.Documents.Open("D:\file1.docx")


    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    Dim picpath As String
    Dim people As String
    Dim rspictures As Variant

    'Dim tmp As Variant

    picpath = "D:\file1.jpg"

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    people = "select * from persons"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(people)

    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst

        Set rspictures = rs.Fields("Picture").Value

           While Not rspictures.EOF
                rspictures.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile (picpath)

                rspictures.MoveNext
           Wend
    End If

    Dim wrdPic As Word.InlineShape

    Set wrdPic = doc1.Bookmarks("picture").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(picpath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)

             wrdPic.ScaleHeight = 10
             wrdPic.ScaleWidth = 10


    Exit Sub
    errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

    End Sub
```

Comment: The only way you can put a picture directly into Word is using copy/paste. Or you need to convert the picture in memory to Base 64, then wrap that in valid Word Open XML in the OPC flat-file format and insert it using the Range.InsertXML method.

Comment: @yaser You're saying your code works but is inefficient?  What's inefficient about it?  On what scale are you doing this that efficiency is an issue?

Comment: This question is too broad in my opinion. If you use Access attachments, it will be slow. Access compresses pictures, and doesn't offer built-in functions to remove this  compression without exporting. While Cindy's idea is good, implementing it will require way too much code for an answer here.