# How do I export a jpg or pdf image to a word document using ms-Access and vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access

The script I am using fills in a word document with data from my Access database using bookmarks. How do I sent a *.jpg  or *.pdf file to a bookmark on a word document? Is it even possible to do this with the method I am currently using? Just adding the image as an attachment in my database (for testing purpose) does not seem to work. The main goal is to paste my signature as a small jpg file on a several places in my document. Any other methods achieving the same goal are also welcome.

```
Private Sub WordExport

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set wApp = New Word.Application

Set rs = Forms!frm_Administration.Recordset
    
'If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveFirst

'Do Until rs.EOF
    
Set wDoc = Nothing

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Test\Test_01.docx")

wDoc.Bookmarks("Anumber_1").Range.Text = Nz(rs!ANumber, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("Anumber_2").Range.Text = Nz(rs!ANumber, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("Anumber_Front").Range.Text = Nz(rs!ANumber, "")

wDoc.SaveAs2 "C:\WordExport\Export\" & StringSave & ".docx"

wDoc.Close False
wApp.Quit

Set wDoc = Nothing
Set wApp = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Previously:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714720/how-to-insert-picture-into-word-doc-from-access-database-using-vba

Comment: If image is in table Attachment field, first save to folder location then load to Word doc from folder.